# Visual Studio 2017 c++ symbols are not loading from microsoft servers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debug-symbols

In VS2010, there is a "Load symbol from" option which I can't find it in VS 2017.
[image]

Now in VS2017, I have "Microsoft Symbol Servers" **checked**.

But the symbol can't be loaded and I got from "Symbol Load Information":

"https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Skipped checking unavailable symbol location."

I don't think the server address is invalid as I have the same setting in VS2010, I checked the "Microsoft Symbol Servers", not the URL.

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. Are you able to find extensions online in the "Extensions and Updates" window?

Comment: You may want to try some of the workarounds here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/issues/670

Comment: I just checked and it's not a firewall issue. Can get extensions no problem.

Comment: @drescherjm: thanks for the suggestion. I might have to try that in the end, but looks quite bit of work.

Comment: Do you really need the symbols? I don't bother to load them because of the extra processing time needed.